# Heteroscedasticity and weighted least square estimator

Tags: econometrics, heteroskedasticity

***"In presence of heteroscedasticity, OLS estimators are unbiased but inefficient"***

Showing the ***unbiased*** part is relatively easy. Some authors have explained the ***inefficiency*** with the help of new variance of the least square estimator.  However, I was asked to show the same thing using the variance of weighted least square estimator ($\hat{\beta^*}$). I proceeded in the following way:-

Consider the model, $Y_t=\alpha+\beta X_t+u_t$   where $u_t$'s are  heteroscedastic.

Suppose ${\sigma _u}^2$ be the constant variance of $u_t$'s under the homoscedastic assumption.

Let $Var(u_t)={\sigma _t}^2$ be the variance of the disturbances under the heteroscedastic assumption.

In Particular, suppose ${\sigma _t}^2=k_t {\sigma _u}^2$, $k_t$'s being some non stochastic constant weights.

Now, consider the above model in deviation form

$y_t=\beta x_t +u_t$, where $y_t=Y_t-E(Y)$, $x_t=X_t-E(X)$

$\Rightarrow \frac{y_t}{k_t}=\beta \frac{x_t}{k_t}+\frac{u_t}{k_t}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{y_t}{k_t}=\beta \frac{x_t}{k_t}+v_t$
where $v_t$ has constant variance ${\sigma _u}^2$

Now, the weighted least square estimator is $\hat{\beta^*}=\frac{\sum \frac{y_t}{k_t}\frac{x_t}{k_t}}{\sum \frac{{x_t}^2}{{k_t}^2}}$

which would eventually give us $Var(\hat{\beta^*})=\frac{{\sigma _u}^2}{\sum \frac{{x_t}^2}{{k_t}^2}}$

Now, under the heteroscedastic assumption, we have $Var(\hat{\beta})=\frac{\sum {x_t}^2{\sigma_t}^2}{(\sum {x_t}^2)^2}$

Now, $$\frac{Var(\hat{\beta^*})}{Var(\hat{\beta})}=\frac{{\sigma _u}^2}{\sum \frac{{x_t}^2}{{k_t}^2}}\times \frac{(\sum {x_t}^2)^2}{\sum {x_t}^2{\sigma_t}^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{Var(\hat{\beta^*})}{Var(\hat{\beta})}=\frac{{\sigma _u}^2}{\sum \frac{{x_t}^2}{{k_t}^2}}\times \frac{(\sum {x_t}^2)^2}{\sum {x_t}^2{k_t\sigma_u}^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{Var(\hat{\beta^*})}{Var(\hat{\beta})}=\frac{(\sum {x_t}^2)^2} {\sum \frac{{x_t}^2}{{k_t}^2} \sum {x_t}^2{k_t}}$$

However, before I could proceed further, my instructor asked me to check it again. He was insisting that I should get something like  $\frac{\sum (a_t b_t)^2}{\sum {a_t}^2 {b_t}^2}$, so that I can use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality  resulting in $Var(\hat{\beta^*})<Var(\hat{\beta})$. This would eventually prove the  ***inefficiency ***  part.

Since I am not getting that form, I think I have made mistakes. I would be happy if somebody can point it.

Comment: Divide by $\sqrt{k_t}$ and not $k_t$, $\dfrac{y_t}{\sqrt{k_t}} = \beta \dfrac{y_t}{\sqrt{k_t}} + \dfrac{u_t}{\sqrt{k_t}}$

Comment: If we divide by $\sqrt{k_t}$, $\frac{u_t}{\sqrt{k_t}}$ would not have constant variance.

Comment: Given that variance of $u_t$ is $\sigma_t^2 = k_t \sigma_u^2$, variance of $\dfrac{u_t}{\sqrt{k_t}}$  is $\sigma^2_u$ and variance of $\dfrac{u_t}{k_t}$  is $\dfrac{\sigma^2_u}{k_t}$

Comment: That's incorrect. $\text{Var}(cX) = c^2\text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point. You are correct. Now it would have constant variance.

Comment: $Var(\frac{u_t}{\sqrt{k_t}})=\frac{1}{k_t} \times Var(u_t)=\frac{1}{k_t} \times k_t {\sigma_u}^2={\sigma_u}^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\hat{\beta}$ be the OLS estimator of $\beta$ in
$$y_t = \beta x_t + u_t$$
Let $\tilde{\beta}$ be the OLS estimator of $\beta$ in
$$\dfrac{y_t}{\sqrt{k_t}} = \beta \dfrac{x_t}{\sqrt{k_t}} + \dfrac{u_t}{\sqrt{k_t}}$$
$\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}) = \dfrac{\sum x_t^2\sigma_t^2}{\left(\sum x_t^2\right)^{2}} $

$\text{Var}(\tilde{\beta}) = \dfrac{\sigma^2_u}{\sum \dfrac{x_t^2}{k_t}} $

So, $\dfrac{\text{Var}(\tilde{\beta})}{\text{Var}(\hat{\beta})} = \dfrac{\left(\sum x_t^2\right)^{2}}{\sum \dfrac{x_t^2}{k_t} \sum {x_t^2}{k_t}} $.

Let $a_t = \dfrac{x_t}{\sqrt{k_t}}$ and $b_t = {x_t}{\sqrt{k_t}}$, and we can rewrite the ratio of variances as

$\dfrac{\text{Var}(\tilde{\beta})}{\text{Var}(\hat{\beta})} = \dfrac{\left(\sum a_tb_t\right)^{2}}{\sum a_t^2 \sum {b_t^2}} \leq 1 $ [By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality]